# Dynamically changing WP_Error message CSS under certain conditions?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, authentication

I have a Wordpress installation and have used a plugin to alter the function `wp_authenticate` (which is a 'pluggable' function in Wordpress).

During the logging in procedure the code runs my wp_authenticate and I can send my own messages back to the user with:

```
$user = new WP_Error('password_reset', __('<strong>DONE</strong>: On its way!'));
```

This appears on the screen in a `div` with the ID 'login_error' so it has a reddish background etc (like an error). I want to change the colour of this for 'good' messages and leave it red for 'bad' messages.

Anyone know how I could do this? The DIV looks hard-coded in the wp_login php file and I don't want to alter any 'core' files.

I wondered about whether it would be possible to use the login_errors filter to maybe override the normal behaviour? Or is there another way to do this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Trying registering your css file on that page slug..

```
 if (is_page('your-page-slug')) {
                wp_register_style('custom-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom-style.css');
                wp_enqueue_style ('custom-css-css');
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vaibs_Cool but I really wanted to be able to change the css dynamically if possible. i.e. if my wp_authenticate has an error to return then it just uses the standard css (red background etc) but if it has an 'information' message then it returns a green box. (hope I'm explaining that clearly?). Basically I need to either overwrite the ID login_error with another css tag or interrupt it somehow. It would have been nice if the WP_Error class allowed you to pass in the relevant css but, as far as I can tell, you can't. ;-)